# How can I design the following code in table format?

Tags: html

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
 <li><input type="checkbox" id="selecctall" /> Selecct All</li>
 @Html.CheckBoxListFor(model => model.HotelIds.CustCodes,
  model => model.Hotels,
  a => a.CustCode,
  a => a.CustName,
  model => model.Selected, a => new { @class = "checkBox1" })
</div>
```

This is the CheckboxListfor which show the Hotel Name and And a checkbox,but it is not coming in proper way.How can I do this

Comment: can you post a fiddle demo

Comment: @Ashley That's my fault. Accidentally deleted in my edit. adding it back now.

Comment: You are using a `li` tag ouside any `ul` or `ol`. What is your desired output? I think it's not clear from that you posted. Are you using this extension? http://mvccbl.com/Examples

Comment: the alignment not coming properly,the check box coming upper in level

Comment: refer this link : http://mvccbl.com/